# Clarification on rejected edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

I recently suggested an edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1099569). It was rejected after receiving 3 reject votes and 2 approve votes.

I do not understand the reason that the edit was edited (the reason `"This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."`. Could I get some opinions from the Meta Community on whether these should have been rejected/approved, and why?

Comment: I'd imagine the `OP please insert code here` part was a big deterrent. That's a completely inappropriate thing to edit into a question; it goes in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the input. barring that, is there anything else wrong with the edit?

Comment: I would say that the question is so bad, and missing so much important information, that it should be closed as NARQ, at least until/unless the OP comes back to add more details.  Editing a post that far gone can't fix all of the problem.  (That's not why it was rejected, just something to keep in mind.)

Comment: +1 for taking the time to see whether your suggestions were approved/rejected and asking why they were rejected when it wasn't clear.  Too many people just don't care if their edits are accepted and make no effort to change their behavior when they suggest improper edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct place for this comment:

> OP please insert code here

is in the Edit Summary or the comments section. Your edit, while a good one, was *also* unfortunately an attempt to comment on the question, which is why it was rejected.

Comment: Note that, as a reviewer, it may have been appropriate to "improve" the suggested edit to keep all of your content minus the inappropriate section.  That would have been best in my opinion, but you, as a suggester, can't rely on reviewers taking the time to improve suggestions.  Rejecting yours is still an appropriate response.

Answer (score 2):

If the question can't be saved through editing (because it's missing critical details from the OP) then the appropriate thing to do is flag it.  Polishing something which is inherently unsalvageable is a waste of time.

Comment: While that is indeed the appropriate response to that SO question in my eyes, it doesn't answer the OP's meta question of why his edit was rejected.